# Should I reduce set variable

Tags: c, performance, conditional-statements, variable-assignment

I have 2 C++ code:

Code 1: Reduce assign variable

```
While(alive)
{
if(health < healthMax) health = healthMax;
}
```

Code 2: Not reduce assign variable

```
While(alive)
{
health = healthMax;
}
```

I don't know how set and get works, but I personally think that set will change/write the data on memory, and get only read memory, so it's best to get and reduce set - that's why I prefer Code 1 more for now. Am I thinking it right?

Thank you for reading :)

Comment: Thank you for answer me. what about the write and read data part? Does write data affect the memory/ram more than read data?

Comment: I'm pretty sure I remember seeing a duplicate of this question about if/when it's worth it to use an `if` to avoid an assignment, but can't find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  The assignment will hopefully compile to a move between registers, which is cheaper than a conditional branch.

If `health` is a global, you might want to manually sink the store to the global out of the loop, but even a store on every iteration isn't too bad.  Repeated stores to the same memory location are cheap, because they will hit in L1 cache.  You can expect a throughput of ~1 per clock, without hogging memory bandwidth for other cores.

Since you tagged this as `assembly`, see the [x86](/questions/tagged/x86) tag wiki for links to performance details for that platform, especially Agner Fog's stuff.  A lot of the concepts are similar for other architectures.

Comment: What about the write and read data part? Does write data affect the memory/ram more than read data - like write will make ram hotter than read, for instance?

Comment: Oh, I can't satisfy if I don't know if write will make ram hotter than read or not?

Comment: @123iamking: a DRAM write command is probably about the same as a DRAM read command for energy consumption.  But that doesn't happen for every store in the asm, because of caching.  There's a huge difference between what the asm does and the memory traffic seen by DRAM.  Do whatever will make your code run in fewer cycles on average, because race-to-sleep is important for CPU core power consumption.

Comment: So when we do a statement like
int a;
a = 3; // code 1
if(a==3){}// Code 2

==> code 1 and code 2 do the same with physic consumption.

Comment: @123iamking: Edit your question so you can use code formatting; I can't make sense of that mess.  But conditional branches will slow your code down.  Always doing a write makes more sense than doing a read / branch / maybe a write in almost all cases.

Comment: sorry :p, 
So when we do a statement like 
int a;  
[Enter]
a = 3; // code 1 
[Enter]
if(a==3){}// Code 2 
[Enter]
==> code 1 and code 2 do the same with physic consumption.

[Enter]
I'm very sorry, StackOverflow don't allow new line for comment or something

Comment: @123iamking:  That's why I said to edit that into your question, instead of messing around with unreadable comments.  But `if(a==3){}` is more efficient because it doesn't do anything.  The `{}` is empty, so the compiler doesn't even need to do the test.  https://godbolt.org/g/Q8GTce.